# ASP.NET on Mac OSX Build Failed (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, asp.net, macos, mono

Ok people, I'm working on some project for school which should be done with ASP.NET, but I have a mac. So I did a research on how to run asp.net web app and followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1g2I9SJZ5XI

In between I runned on to some error with mono https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/498
Managed to solve it with building mono 4.1.0 from github

So after all that, I tried to build and here is the output:

```
http://pastebin.com/mtzVj9S7
```

When I try to use **Run K Commands** and **k web**:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to load application or execute command 'Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting'. Available commands: web, kestrel, gen, ef.
  at Microsoft.Framework.ApplicationHost.Program.ThrowEntryPointNotfoundException (Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.DefaultHost host, System.String applicationName, System.Exception innerException) <0x35aa2b8 + 0x0014f> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.Framework.ApplicationHost.Program.ExecuteMain (Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.DefaultHost host, System.String applicationName, System.String[] args) <0x347f3d0 + 0x00157> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.Framework.ApplicationHost.Program.Main (System.String[] args) <0x2987d50 + 0x00353> in <filename unknown>:0
```

When I try to use **Run K Commands** and **kpm restore**:

```
  System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: ApplicationName='bower', CommandLine='install', CurrentDirectory='/Users/djordjevanjek/Sites/ZdravaHrana', Native error= Cannot find the specified file
  at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start_noshell (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo, System.Diagnostics.Process process) <0x36a2cd8 + 0x00e03> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start_common (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo, System.Diagnostics.Process process) <0x36a2b48 + 0x000a7> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo) <0x36a27f8 + 0x0004f> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.Framework.PackageManager.ScriptExecutor.Execute (Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Project project, System.String scriptName, System.Func`2 getVariable) <0x30d7f68 + 0x0046f> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.Framework.PackageManager.RestoreCommand+<RestoreForProject>d__62.MoveNext () <0x30a4af8 + 0x01207> in <filename unknown>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () <0x18897b0 + 0x00035> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x1887170 + 0x000b7> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x18870e0 + 0x00084> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x1887090 + 0x0003f> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () <0x1b7d1b0 + 0x0001f> 24246 in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.Framework.PackageManager.RestoreCommand+<ExecuteCommand>d__61.MoveNext () <0x301fbd8 + 0x00643> in <filename unknown>:0
```

Hopefully this will be enough input to help me about this.

Comment: I'm running against the same errors.

Comment: @hugo feel you bro, let me know if you find an answer.

Comment: This might be a more suitable question for http://serverfault.com/.

Comment: @AdrianJ.Moreno tbh I had a doubt where to post it, at the end I thought that stackoverflow is more suitable, maybe I'm wrong...

Comment: @hugo Hey mate I found a solution, hopefully it will help you, cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to run an web app.
Here is what I had to do:

1. Open up terminal, `cd` to your web app directory.
2. Type `dnu restore`

   2a. If you get result like this `-bash: dnu: command not found`

   Type `source dnvm.sh` and then go back run `dnu restore` again.

   2b. If it starts restoring but at the end you get something like: `http://pastebin.com/MLES7QPn`

   Run these `sudo npm install -g bower` and `sudo npm install -g grunt-cli`
   and then go back run `dnu restore` again.
3. After you did restoring without errors, type `dnx . kestrel`

   3a. If you look up at the `http://localhost:5001` and get something like this

   `kqueue() FileSystemWatcher has reached the maximum nunmber of files to watch.`

   run this command in your terminal (it's an mono bug) `export MONO_MANAGED_WATCHER=false`
4. `http://localhost:5001` Should be working now, Cheers...

Hopefully I managed to help someone, here are the sources where I found my answers: http://andreizubov.blogspot.ru/2015/04/getting-started-with-net-on-os-x-and.html http://www.cnblogs.com/haogj/p/4493240.html

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have much time, just sign up to [AWS](http://aws.amazon.com) and launch a Windows server.  A 4GB box should cost less than 10 cents per hour if it is running.

Then install the free Microsoft Remote Desktop from the Mac App Store.

This is the least intrusive way to get Windows on your Mac.  If you need 10 hours to complete your homework, it should you less than one dollar.